# To do the same in python output should be same as the scala output

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

[LINK TO data.csv](https://github.com/1576dkm/Spark-Data/blob/master/data.csv)
In scala the code gives an Array of string but in python I wanted the same output just like scala :
**Code in Scala:**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Test_Parquet")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val parquetDF = spark.read.csv("data.csv")
    parquetDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("Parquet")
    val rdd = spark.read.parquet("Parquet").rdd
    val header = rdd.first()

    val rdd1 = rdd.filter(_ != header).map(x => x.toString)
    rdd1.foreach(println)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [Canada,47;97;33;94;6]
>       [Canada,59;98;24;83;3]
>       [Canada,77;63;93;86;62]
>       [China,86;71;72;23;27]
>       [China,74;69;72;93;7]
>       [China,58;99;90;93;41]
>       [England,40;13;85;75;90]
>       [England,39;13;33;29;14]
>       [England,99;88;57;69;49]
>       [Germany,67;93;90;57;3]
>       [Germany,0;9;15;20;19]
>       [Germany,77;64;46;95;48]
>       [India,90;49;91;14;70]
>       [India,70;83;38;27;16]
>       [India,86;21;19;59;4]

**Code in Python:**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_Parquet").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

parquetDF = spark.read.csv("data.csv")

parquetDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("Parquet")
rdd = spark.read.parquet("Parquet").rdd
header = rdd.first()
print(header)
rdd1 = rdd.filter(lambda line: header != line).map(lambda x: str(x))
rdd1.foreach(print)
```

**The output of the python is different than the scala were i'm doing the same thing in python**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `rdd1.foreach(print)` should work, but since you're converting from a `DataFrame` you will get `Row` objects instead.

I think the following should work:

```
rdd1.map(list).foreach(print)
```

Difference:

```
df.rdd.foreach(print)
# Row(Name='John', gender='Male', state='GA')
# Row(Name='Mary', gender='Female', state='GA')
# Row(Name='Alex', gender='Male', state='NY')
# Row(Name='Ana', gender='Female', state='NY')
# Row(Name='Amy', gender='Female', state='NY')

df.rdd.map(list).foreach(print)
# ['John', 'Male', 'GA']
# ['Mary', 'Female', 'GA']
# ['Alex', 'Male', 'NY']
# ['Ana', 'Female', 'NY']
# ['Amy', 'Female', 'NY']
```

**Note**: *If this is not your exact problem, then please provide the actual and expected output*